# Dart:io ошибка при чтени файла

Tags: dart

Изучаю библиотеку dart:io.
Проблема при выполнении примера кода из документации `

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() async {
  var config = File('D:\\wordsone.txt');
  var stringContents = await config.readAsString();
  print('В файле ${stringContents.length} значений.');
} `
```

Error when reading 'dart_file.dart': No such file or directory.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал в собственном коде и с массой других примеров. Всегда такая ошибка. Файл не читается даже из Lib проекта. Уважаемые участники сообщества, прошу помочь решить проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: приложите структуру проекта в развернутом виде с именем файла

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо, что откликнулись.

Comment: Пока пробовал решить проблему самостоятельно обнаружил, что всё выполняется через консоль отладки (f5). Ошибка только при запуске через терминал. Интересно, почему? Какая то проблема доступа к файлам из терминала? Команда cd при этом видит и директорию и сам файл.